# No automatic thumbnail generation

Tags: nautilus, icons, cache, thumbnails

I recently decided to do a fresh install of 13.10 and ran into a quite peculiar problem. It seems that thumbnails are not generated automatically, when I open a folder in nautilus I can only see a loading icon. If I refresh the folder ONE new icon is generated, hence I have to press <kbd>F5</kbd> repeatedly in order to get a full set of thumbnails which can be quite frustrating. This happens regardless of filetype, even folder icons fail to generate until <kbd>F5</kbd> has been pressed.

So far I have tried to delete the `~/.thumbnails` folder and just to be sure I've given the newly generated folder a 777 permission via `chmod` but the problem still persists so I am starting to suspect that something may be wrong with my `libgnome-desktop` library but that's just a wild guess at the moment.

Any help or suggestions are would be appreciated since I am running out of ideas of how to resolve this issue.